# Increase upload request length limit in Kestrel

Tags: file-upload, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, kestrel-http-server

I am running an ASP.NET Core web app and want to upload large files.

I know that when running IIS, the limits can be changed via `web.config`:

```xml
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" /> 
...
<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
```

**How can you do the equivalent while running the new ASP.NET Core Kestrel web server?**

I get the exception *"Request body too large."*

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I found [this helpful announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/267) that confirms there is a 28.6 MB body size limit starting with ASP.NET Core 2.0, but more importantly shows how to get around it!

To summarize:

For a single controller or action, use the [`[DisableRequestSizeLimit]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.disablerequestsizelimitattribute) attribute to have no limit, or the [`[RequestSizeLimit(100_000_000)]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.requestsizelimitattribute) to specify a custom limit.

To change it globally, inside of the `BuildWebHost()` method, inside the `Program.cs` file, add the `.UseKestrel` option below:

```csharp
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
  .UseStartup<Startup>()
  .UseKestrel(options =>
  {
    options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = null;
  }
```

For additional clarity, you can also refer to the [Kestrel options documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?tabs=aspnetcore2x#kestrel-options).

Comment: Sorry, it feels weird to answer my own question, but I hope others will benefit from this.

Comment: Answering your own question is [perfectly fine](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and you are encouraged to do so any time if you have a question that you believe is useful! So thanks for researching! :)

Comment: Hey! can you tell what's the max Request header size on Kestrel?

Comment: I am not aware of any absolute limitations other than that of the corresponding data type's max value (`Int32.MaxValue`) as found on the configurable `KestrelServerLimits.MaxRequestHeadersTotalSize` property. You could try asking a new question on SO.

Answer (score 6):

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46738667) is for ASP.NET Core 2.0, but I would like to provide the solution for .NET Core 3.x web API.

Your code in `program.cs` must be like this to work:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                webBuilder.UseKestrel(options =>
                {
                    options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = null;
                });
            });
}
```